# Technical differences in doing nothing vs. pass ""

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword, quotes

I have learned that to do nothing in python, one may use the `pass` keyword:

```
if True:
    pass
```

However, when I do this:

```
if True:
    ""
```

I seemingly get the exact same result. Nothing happens.

What exactly happens when I call `pass` vs. when I call `""`? Is one minusculely faster or more efficient?

Comment: Usually we use the `Ellipsis` object rather than an (interned) empty string, but the net effect is the same.